# How do protection, defense, and blocking relate?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We do not currently have any tag guidance for [protection](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protection), [defense](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/defense), and [blocking](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blocking). These concepts overlap, and it's not clear when one of these should be applied rather than another.

My best guess

- [protection](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protection) protective equipment
- [defense](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/defense) fighting techniques that are defensive and not offensive
- [blocking](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blocking) same as defense?

Comment: The best defense is a ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would look to do this:

- create a tag wiki for [blocking](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blocking)
- also create a tag wiki for [defense](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/defense), it is about defense in general which can encompass many things (like several blocks or even some attacks)
- create a new tag [protective-equipment](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protective-equipment) (status: done!) and synonymize [protection](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protection) with it. We could eliminate that tag but it seems to be a bit of a go-to one, so rather than killing and black listing it we'll just synonymize (which means people can still use it but it will get replaced by [protective-equipment](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protective-equipment) automatically)